# Multicursor selection in Jupyter without mouse

Tags: python, r, julia, jupyter-notebook

Well-known way to use multicursor selection in jupyter notebook is to press Alt and then use the mouse. However is there some way to do it without mouse? E.g. like Ctrl+Shift in Visual Studio.

Doing it with mouse is much more slower than it can be done with keyboard.

Comment: Anyone have an answer besides the one for vim bindings?

Comment: @KenWilliams Do you like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70016750/16751401)? (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like vi/vim keybindings, take a look at the excellent [jupyter-vim-binding](https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding), which adds additional keyboard editing modes to Jupyter notebook, similar to Vim.

After installing this extension, as in Vim, you can perform multicursor selection (block selection) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: I keep getting  Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed. And they don't install with pip.

Comment: @cybervigilante - assuming you're on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev`

Answer (score 13):

On GitHub, I found [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4761#issuecomment-791362169). It is not precisely what you asked for, but speeds up my use of Jupyter considerably.

- Place cursor in the desired spot
- Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- Hold your left mouse button and drag mouse over the lines where you want a cursor

This places the mouse cursor in the same column of each line. It works particularly well if you need a mouse cursor at the beginning of each line.

As hychou pointed out in the comments, for Mac you have to hold option and then drag your mouse.

Comment: Holding just Alt is enough for this.

Comment: What about Mac?

Comment: @becko for Mac, hold option + mouse drag